# Archiving Windows Server Service Bus messages

Tags: servicebus

The MSDN documentation for the BrokeredMessage.Complete method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete.aspx) describes the method as this: "Completes the receive operation of a message and indicates that the message should be marked as processed and deleted or archived."

In my use of this method I've only seen the message deleted once it is processed.  This is the one and only instance I've seen in the MSDN documentation, blogs, or anywhere else about Service Bus being capable of archiving old messages.

I could archive the message myself as part of my code that reads and processes a message and then marks it complete.  But is it possible to make Windows Server Service Bus archive completed messages for me?  If so, how do you turn on and configure this feature?

In case the difference matters, I am using the locally hosted Windows Server Service bus, not the Azure version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Service Bus doesn't archive your messages. I'm going to follow up w/ the documentation folks on what that was supposed to express.

Comment: It's a documentation bug and will be fixed when the docs get updated sometime later today, Redmond time. Thank you for the feedback, Mike.